# "catching" links in regex using php ignoring inline js

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck trying to make a regex in PHP that catches the link and its content from a html page (which I have no control over) and replaces it with a link of mine.

i.e.:

```
<a style="position:absolute;more_styles:more;" href="http://www.google.co.il/" class="something">This is the content</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a style="position:absolute;more_styles:more;" href="my_function('http://www.google.co.il/')" class="something">This is the content</a>
```

This is the regex that I wrote:

```
$content = preg_replace('|<a(.*?)href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'][^>]*>(.*?)</a>|i','$3',$content);
```

This works well with all the links except links like:

```
<a href="http://google.co.il" onclick="if(MSIE_VER()>=4){this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('http://www.google.co.il')}" class='brightgrey rightbar' style='font-size:12px'><b>Make me the home page!</b></a>
```

Obviously, the regexp stops at "MSIE_VER()>" because of the "[^>]*" part and i get the wrong content when I use "$3".

I tried almost every option to make this work but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Thank you all in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is trying to do something different that to add my_function - it tries to remove the starting  tag and replace it with url only. There are several ways to acheieve your declared goal (i.e. substituing my_function to all hrefs) , the most pragmafic would be:

```
$content = preg_replace('|href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']|i',"href=\"my_function('$1')\"",$content);
```

if you need more prudent approach than I would use

```
$content = preg_replace('|(<a.*?)href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'](.*?</a>)|i',"$1href=\"my_function('$2')\"$3",$content);
```

last but not least if you need removing  tag rather than what you have written, let me know there is million ways to do it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick response.

I made the whole replace because I don't want to affect the "base","link" and etc. tags, only the "a" tag... 

Your regex replaces all of them..

Comment: Well, it has a problem like I said. If I replace all of the "link" tags the html stylesheet doesn't apply...

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand at all which problem you are talkng about.

Comment: Didn't see your edit before.. Everything works now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

By default .* will take evryting it can - eg. it takes onclick argument, because regex is still valid - replace "." with [^\"] - it will tell regexp to take evrything excluding " ( which cannot be in URL )

```
$content = preg_replace('|<a(.*?)href=[\"\']([^"]*?)[\"\'][^>]*>(.*?)</a>|i','$3',$content);
```

Comment: this does not address the bug mentioned, but somethig else. you have protected it from including " in $2, but it is already done by using non-greedy operator? together with [\"\'] group. However it does not solve the > problem.